# Android url Api by environment

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Good day. How can I make my application's android url configurable. That is to say; I currently have to change the url
 and compile to test in development; Do the same process to test in QA. I don't know if that is necessary or there is a way that without recompiling from android studio I can try in one environment or another. Thank you

Comment: Use build types or product flavors, along with `buildConfigField`: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips#share-custom-fields-and-resource-values-with-your-app-code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds that you are trying to get a different url based on app buildType. You can easily do that through gradle, but you need some knowledge of how it works.
In short:

Assuming you url configuration is in you app module (not gonna talk about multi-modules here) go to you Apps `build.gradle` file and create as many buildTypes as you need, and add the appropriate url within each type:

```
buildTypes {

    debug {
      buildConfigField("String", "API_URL", "<dev_url>")
    }

    qa {
      buildConfigField("String", "API_URL", "<qa_url>")
    }

    release {
      buildConfigField("String", "API_URL", "<prod_url>")
    }
}
```

then you can easily use that field by calling: `BuildConfig.API_URL` and it will yield the correct value of the variant you use.

For more complete information about that and more please check [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you need to enclose your URLs in another set of (escaped) double quotes: `buildConfigField("String", "API_URL", "\"https://api.example.com\"")`